# Secure user authentication

Tags: algorithm, security, authentication, key

I was thinking of implementing secure user authentication using following approach. 
So how about starting with asking the username and submit it to the server. On submission, the server would look up for password related to that user. It would append it with some value (say timestamp or any other additional value which can be sent across back to client). It would encrypt it using some public key algorithm and send it back to client. Now the client would be prompted for password. Now when the user enters the password and submits, the password value would be appended with same value which was appended to password in server; generate the encrypted string using same public key algorithm and compare with the value received from server. It they are equal, the user is authenticated and session can be created or otherwise, it fails.

I wanted to know if this approach is feasible and efficient in terms of performance; and how difficult it would be to breach this approach.

Comment: The algorithm you have sketched out is somewhat similar to [cyptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

Comment: @AndersLindahl.. Wow, I didnt know this concept of cryptographic nonce. Yes, it seems bit similar. And I guess my approach would avoid replay attacks and brute force attack. Do correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

This protocol is very bad because it allows an attacker to use offline methods to crack the password. It means that the attacker can send only one request to the server, he will receive the encrypted password+timstamp (which is basically a hash of the password) and then he will be able to brute-force the password offline. Using a good dictionary, a good set of rules and a few GPUs, this can be done very easily.

Actually, the server should never sent to the client any information related to the password (except "the password is correct" or "the password is incorrect").

Comment: I do agree it would be inappropriate to send password info as response. But since it would be encryption of (actual password against username+timestamp or any other dynamic value), the response value would differ every time and  it would be quite difficult for attacker to apply brute force attack. May be, we could apply password failure limit ie. after 3 failed attempts, the account would be locked.

Comment: `enc(password+username+timestamp)` is basically a hash of the password, username+timestamp being the salt. So the server sends a hash of the password to anyone who requests it. This hash can then be cracked offline. Moreover you can't lock the account after a failed attempt because the attacker can test passwords without server interaction, which mean that the server is not aware that the client made a failed attempt.

Comment: @Thomash..Are you saying that the attacker would retrieve different server responses and would eventually come out with the actual password value on the basis of collected values. Then I would keep password change policy enforcing user to change password in monthly basis or so. Also, the timestamp can be replaced with some dynamic value conformed between user and server.

Comment: The attacker doesn't even need the actual password, just anything that hashes to the same thing. You're literally sending the client exactly what it needs to get in. Moreover, the client could just be cracked to validate *anything* entered, since there's no server-side verification.

Comment: @Geobits. In response to  "...just anything that hashes to the same thing.." , how come it would return the same value when i am hashing it with dynamic value every time. And I guess  with password change policy, it would make it more difficult for attacker to work out the password.

Comment: If the server sends back `hash(pass+user+time)`, then it only needs to find something that hashes to `hash(pass+user+time)`. For example, if the username is "test", pass is "abc123", and time is "12345", then it only has to find something that hashes to "abc123test12345". There's no need for it to figure out which parts are which.

Comment: @Geobits..Do you mean to say, the attacker might have someone' password and use the hash value generated by it to reverse engineer other passwords?